# Repository object in several services

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, architecture

I'm doing my free time project in .Net core 2.2

I've decoupled my project in 4 parts

1) DataLayer
2) RepositoryLayer
3) Services
4) Web-API layer

I have one model and let's make for example it **IPerson**.
Then I have Generic repository here

```
class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity, IPhysicalPersonEntity
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        private DbSet<TEntity> _entities;
        string errorMessage = string.Empty;

        public Repository(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _entities = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
        public void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity is null");
            }

            _entities.Remove(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _entities
                .AsEnumerable();
        }

        public TEntity GetByIdentifyNumber(int identifyNumber)
        {
            return _entities
                .SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == identifyNumber);
        }

        public void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            if(entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity is null");
            }

            _entities.Add(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Remove(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity is null");
            }

            _entities.Remove(entity);
        }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity is null");
            }

            var currentEntity = _entities
                .SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == entity.Id);

            currentEntity = entity;

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

As you mentioned the third layer is for **Services**, so I have here services for

1. Add person
2. Delete the person.
3. Edit person.
4. Find the person with id.
5. Add person recommendations.
6. Etc.

Each service is a single class with a single interface.
I know that in each service I should use my repository object and methods.

But my questions are:

- How to handle one repository object in each service?
- I don't want to make each repository object in each service.
  (Or maybe that is correct way doing it?)
- What is the best practise in that situation?
- Am I doing my architecture in an incorrect way?

Answer (score 0):

I use the same structure which is `DataLayer`, `Repository`, `WebAPI`.

And I built the structure as follows

- My repository layer is the same of yours
- In my WebAPI layer, i use BaseController and other controller are derived the BaseController

  ```
  public class ApiBaseController<T> : ApiController where T : class {

  [HttpPut]
  [Authorize]
  [ActionName("Update")]
  [Produces("application/json")]
  public T Put([FromBody]T entity) // Update
  {
      using (MyContext db = new MyContext()) 
      {
         repository.Update(updateElement);
         return entity;
      }
  }


  [HttpPost]
  [Authorize]
  [ActionName("Add")]
  [Produces("application/json")]
  public T Post([FromBody]T entity)//Add new record
  {
      try
      {
          lock (LockObjectAdd)
          {
              using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
              {
                  Repository<T> repository = new Repository<T>(db);
                  repository.Add(entity);
                  return entity;
              }
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          throw;
      }
  }

  }
  ```

and controllers are created like that ;

```
public class ApiUserController : ApiBaseController<DataLayer.Models.User> { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Architecture and best practices it depend on about your project, sometimes you dont need Datalayer
 and service separate but sometimes you can separate it, but you can use this link for
 repository pattern implementation:
[Generic-Repository-Pattern-in-ASP-NET](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generic-repository-pattern-in-asp-net-core/)